# Retrieving records from pivot table which match all results

Tags: mysql, sql, angularjs, sqlite

I am making a place where I can store recipes that I have made but am having trouble with my database. I have 3 tables, a recipes, an ingredients and a baseingredients table.

```
Recipe Table
ID int
name varchar
steps varchar

BaseIngredients Table
ID int
name varchar

Ingredients Table
ID int
baseID int
recipeID int
measurement varchar
```

So everytime I enter in a recipe I am asked for the ingredients in it, and it checks to see if it exists in the base ingredients table, if so it uses this baseingredient ID and fills in a record in the ingredients table.

My issue is, on searching for recipes, I want to be able to search on the ingredients I have in my fridge. So if I type in Eggs and bread, it will come up with an egg sandwich. However with the query Im using, it will find all the recipes that have eggs in it and return that back, so for example it would find cakes, pancakes (Whatever contains eggs really). How can I limit it so that it shows all the recipes that contain only the ingredients that I have listed as a search parameter.

```
select recipes.id, recipes.name from recipes inner join ingredients on recipes.id = ingredients.recipeID inner join baseingredient on ingredients.baseID = baseingredient.id where  baseingredient.name = 'Eggs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select r.id
      ,r.name
from recipes r
where exists (select * 
              from ingredients i1
              inner join baseIngredients b1
                on i1.id=b1.baseId
              where i1.recipeID = r.id
               and b1.name = 'ingredient_1'
             )
  ...
  and exists (select * 
              from ingredients iN
              inner join baseIngredients bN
                on iN.id=bN.baseId
              where iN.recipeID = r.id
               and bN.name = 'ingredient_N'
             )
```

**EDIT:** the above query will return all recipes whose ingredient lists *include* those you specified. If I misunderstood your question and what you want is actually only the recipes that use *no other ingredients* than those you specify, try this:

```
select r.id
      ,r.name
from recipes r
where not exists (select * 
                  from ingredients i
                  inner join baseIngredients b
                    on i.id=b.baseId
                  where i.recipeID = r.id
                  and b.name not in ('ingredient_1', 'ingredient_2', ..., 'ingredient_N')
```

where `ingredient_1`, `ingredient_2`, etc should obviously be replaced by those you enter in your search.

Comment: Im not really sure how that works, I have tried this query on my database as well and it doesnt seem to be doing anything either. Maybe Im just not understanding it correctly. In the example I gave, if I typed in Eggs as an ingredient for a recipe that contained eggs and flour, it would come back with this result even though Ive not actually specified that I have flour.

Comment: ok I think I understand what you mean, tell me if I'm correct: you would like to return recipes that contain **only** the ingredients you specify? So if you type _eggs_ and _flower_ you don't want to see any recipe that contain something else than those two ingredients?

Side question then: if you type _eggs_, _flower_ and _butter_, would you like to return recipes that contain only _eggs_ and _flower_?

Comment: Yes that's correct, so if I type in just eggs, I don't want to see any results that contain anything more than just eggs, as for the side question, if I typed those three in, returning a recipe with just eggs and flour will be fine as I have those two ingredients so am able to make the recipe

Comment: @bob565 then the edit I made to my answer should do just that

Comment: Yea this seems to be working, thanks for that. Would you mind explaining whats actually happening here, I dont really understand how that query is working.

Comment: @bob565 translated in english, this query would say "get me all the recipes for which there does not exist ingredients whose name is not in this list". For each recipe (`r.id`), the subquery will try to get, in the list of ingredients linked to that recipe, any record where the ingredient name does not fit in the provided list. If the subquery returns any record, then the outer `where`clause is not true (because there _does_ exist such records) and the recipe is not included in the result set.